# AttributeError in Django Overlapping validation checking

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i am cretaing a validation rule in djano to check overlapping but i am getting this error, can you guys help me

there is two data field , when the data field will be overlapped than validation error will rise.

```
start_r= model.integerfield(blank=True, Null=True)
end_t=model.intergerfield(blank=True,Null=True)
```

form.py

```
class CheckForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def clean(self):
           start_r = cleaned_data.get("start_r",[])
           end_t =cleaned_data.get("end_t",[])
           if (start_r.end >= end_t.start) and (start_r.start <= end_t.end):
              raise ValidationError("Overlap not allowed.")
```

i am getting error this one **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'end'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with `start_r.end` or `end_t.start`? The error message says `start_r` is None, so there is no `end` attribute. But even if the `start_r` is not None, those fields are defined as an integer, not an object.

To access the cleaned_data, you need to use one of the 2 commands bellow:

- `cleaned_data = super(CheckForm, self).clean()`
- `cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data`

If you explain what you need in more detail, I could help better.

Comment: Hi @erdem i can explain

Comment: Hi @Erdem i am struggling to find a logic find the overlapping, can you give me a logic

Comment: Why do you need to find overlapping? Do you mean to compare dates or something else? Can you explain with a real data example?

Comment: yes sure so if start_r=4 , and end_t=9 and in second time if anyone fill the data with start_r=5 and end_t=15, in second time someone filled the start_r with 5 so then 5 is overlappinf with first entry , then validation error  will rise

Comment: As much as I understand, you want to compare with the previous value so you need to store the previous values. In the clean method, you have only 2 variables, one of them is 'start_r' and the other one is 'end_t'. There are no previous values in the clean method. You need to change your perspective. Btw, I still didn't understand what 'start_r' and 'end_t' represents.

Comment: Hi Start_r and end_t are model. filed , in start_r field i am inputting data for start api time and end_t saving api response time. so start_r may be 1 second and end_t can be 2  second. but can not overlap when i will put data in django form .py.